# How to add actionListener to each Button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

It might be confusing for some to answer this but I will try to put my question in the best way. I am working with jdbc and gui. Basically I want to display (in buttons format) the particular data received from my sql database. I could get the data correctly and put it to my array of buttons as their names. In other words, I have an ArrayList of buttons with different names/texts received from my database. Thus i really need to make an arraylist of buttons since data are dynamically populated. My problem is, I am so confused of how am going to create an actionListener to each button. Everytime each button is clicked, it must show the values associated with its name. I don't know how am i supposed to pass at least the names of the buttons to my actionListener method (or action Event Handler). If you find it confusing, here is the code for my buttons.

```
todayTaskButton.add(new JButton(taskForToday.get(i)));
todayTaskButton.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,75));
todayTaskButton.get(i).setBackground(Color.GRAY);
todayTaskButton.get(i).setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.PLAIN,30));
todayTaskButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.WHITE);
todayTaskButton.get(i).setFocusable(false);
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly there are so many ways you might achieve this, the problem is picking the right one for you...

## You could...

Create a anonymous class for each button, each time your create them

```
todayTaskButton.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...
    }
});
```

While this can work, it can make the code really messy, you also still need a way to map the action back to the button in some way, which can be done using the `actionCommand` property or using the `source` property if you don't mind iterating through the list of available buttons

## You could...

Create a purpose build class which implements `ActionListener` for each button, which possibly takes some kind of reference to the data

```
todayTaskButton.get(i).addActionListener(new TodayActionListener(taskForToday.get(i)));
```

This is a little more focused, as you don't really care about the button, as you have the "today" value for the listener, so all the normally repeated code could be isolated into a single class and you would simply pass in the "variable" element

## You could...

Take full advantage of the `Action` API and make individual, self contained actions for each button...

```
public class TaskAction extends AbstractAction {

    public TodayAction(String task) {
        putValue(NAME, task);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Specific action for task
    }
    
}
```

Then you could simply use

```
todayTaskButton.add(new JButton(new TaskAction(taskForToday.get(i))));
```

While this is similar to the previous option, the `Action` is a self contained unit of work and has a number of properties which the `JButton` can use to configure it self.  The `Action` can also be re-used for `JMenuItem`s and key bindings, making it incredibly flexible

Have a closer look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: Perfect answer sir! Thank you so much. Honestly, I am still exploring java swing programming. We are assigned to create a project and this is my first time to make one. So thanks for the guide!

Comment: Sir. It completely work. Thank you so much. I will read more about the link you suggested to further understand this. I just copied your code by the way..Thank you!

Comment: Would any one like to highlight the reason for the down vote? How does the answer not answer the ops question? In what way(s) could it be improved?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the name of the button to the ActionListener. It is automatically detected. You just need to implement the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in you class.

Then add the listener to the button :

```
todayTaskButton.get(i).addActionListener(this);
```

In your `actionPerformed` method, you can do:

```
JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
String text = b.getText();
```

Comment: Sir. Thank you for the answer. I've got the main idea. However, I am used to implementing actionListener through this way, 
JButton.addActionListener(this::methodName) {}

Comment: continuation: then implementing the methodName in my class. Can you please help me how am i supposed to implement your suggestion in the way i am used to? Thank you so much sir