# How to set the ActionListener for multiple different nameless JButtons. How can they be treated independently when they all have the same or no name?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Here is an example. I have a grid of different buttons (adding each to Grid Layout) and I don't want names for any of them but want to carry out different commands for each of them. How can I tell the difference when Overriding actionPerformed?

```
/* MULTIPLE BLANK JBUTTONS WHAT DO????????? */
    JButton temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_WIDTH*BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
        temp = new JButton();
        temp.setActionEvent("a" + i);
        temp.addActionListener(new ActionListener{
                //Anonymous Class????? Is there a better way?
            }
        });
        this.add(temp);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when each of these buttons are pressed?

Comment: You cant create JButton without its name. if you have a large number of JButtons and you dont want to write a name for each of them then make an array of Jbuttons and refer each by its index.

Comment: Use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` which, by default, returns the text of the button or you could use an instance of a custom `Action` which is seeded with the required information you need for each cell, see [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: As demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088447/how-to-add-actionlistener-to-each-button/37088676#37088676), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065186/after-adding-imageicons-to-jbuttons-buttons-no-longer-work/37067594#37067594), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880846/using-multiple-jbuttons-with-the-same-label-in-java/35880892#35880892), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863894/how-to-use-actionperformed-actionevent-e-with-more-that-one-button/34864401#34864401)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JButton#setActionCommand(String)` to create a unique identifier for each `JButton` in your loop.

In this situation it's better to have private implementation of `ActionListener` interface in your container (`JPanel`, `JFrame`, ...) instead of having an anonymous `ActionListener` implementation in the loop. It's cleaner in this way and on the other hand as **@MadProgrammer** mentioned does not provide a `public` access to `actionPerformed` as well.

So In the `actionPerformed` method you can use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` to find out which button is pressed. For example:

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

    public void init(){

        MyButtonActionListener actionListener = new MyButtonActionListener();
        /* MULTIPLE BLANK JBUTTONS WHAT DO????????? */
        JButton temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_WIDTH*BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
            temp = new JButton();
            //temp.setActionEvent("a" + i);
            temp.setActionCommand(""+i); // <- Unique Identifier
            temp.addActionListener(actionListener);
            this.add(temp);
        }
    }

    private static class MyButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            // Decide what to do for each button:
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

This can be boosted if you create a two dimensional array of `JButton` and according to the `actionCommand` you can find out which button is pressed by doing the calculation of indices in the two dimensional array.

Hope this help.

Comment: *"In this situation it's better for your Container (JPanel, JFrame, ...) to implement the ActionListener interface instead of having an anonymous ActionListener implementation in the loop."* - But now you're exposing `public void actionPerformed` which should never be called by any external class, not a good design choice. You also don't need to set the `actionCommand` property directly, as it will default to the text of the button, but that comes down to context. However, generally, a better solution would be to use an `Action` which could be configured with the requieed information

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Many thanks for teaching me. I advised this way of implementing `ActionListener` instead of implementing anonymous actionListeners inline in the code, for a cleaner and a better formatted code. For correcting the flaw of publicity of `public void actionPerformed`, will it be good to create a private member variable of type `ActionListener` and then use that as the `ActionListener` for the buttons?

Comment: So are you going to use a inner class or anonymous class for the private field?

Comment: I was thinking about a private static inner class.

Comment: Thank you sir!! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm editing my answer with the help of my master @MadProgrammer. You can accept this answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Sorry I am new to swing and still a bit confused. How can I prevent actionPerformed from being accessed externally? Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ActionListener GUIBoard.java /GUITest/src line 32 Java Problem

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution makes a lot more sense now.